# What is the build step for Junit in Jenkins job?

Tags: junit, jenkins

I am using Jenkins CI to test a Java Project. I already wrote my tests and ran them in Eclipse and everything is fine. However, I don't know what to write in the build step in the Jenkins Job.

My repository is this: (the Junit tests are in TestDFA.java)

```
D:\GIT\CFLOW
│   Main.java
│   PreProcessor.java
│
├───cflow
│   │   DFA.java
│   │
│   ├───exceptions
│   │       DeadState.java
│   │       InvalidStateException.java
│   │       InvalidTransitionException.java
│   │
│   └───tests
│           TestDFA.java
│
└───libs
        junit.jar
```

I have another Python job and all that I needed to write was "python testDFA.py" but with  Java it's very hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to run your test cases with [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html) or with an [ant](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-unit-testing/running-tests-with-ant.html) script. There should be a Jenkins plugin for that, or just call ant/maven from a command line build step.

Comment: Thank you, I finally made it, there is my build.xml for tests https://gist.github.com/andrefreitas/5118442